# Why @echo appears in output to stdout in my Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

i created a new git repo where i want to add all my terminal
tools. I implement one makefile to compile automatically all
tools i add to src-folder. It works but i have one issue i
really dont understand.

If there is more as one tool in src folder an "@echo" is
printed out. I really cannot find why:

Perhaps someone out there can find it. I want really know whats
wrong here.

```
SRCDIR=src

OUTDIR=trg
OUTDIRBIN=$(OUTDIR)/bin
OUTDIROBJ=$(OUTDIR)/obj

CXX=g++
CXXCHK=clang++

CXXFLAGS=-std=c++20 -Wall
CXXFLAGSREL=$(CXXFLAGS) -O2 -s -g0 -DNDEBUG
CXXFLAGSDEB=$(CXXFLAGS) -O0 -g
CXXFLAGSREAL=$(CXXFLAGS)
CXXFLAGSADD=

LFLAGS=-static -o
LFLAGSREL=$(LFLAGS)
LFLAGSDEB=$(LFLAGS)
LFLAGSADD=

SRCDIRSTOOLS  := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -maxdepth 3 -type d)
SRCFILESTOOLS := $(foreach dir,$(SRCDIRSTOOLS),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp))

.PHONY: all

all: clean debug

define addFlags
    $(eval LFLAGSADD=$(if $(strip $(findstring 4dsql,$1)),-l4d_sql,))
endef

define compile
    @echo "\nSource :" $1
    $(call addFlags,$1)
    @ $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGSREAL) $(CXXFLAGSADD) $(LFLAGSADD) $(LFLAGS) $(addprefix $(OUTDIRBIN)/,$(notdir $(patsubst %.cpp,%,$1))) $1
    @echo "  Tool :" $(addprefix $(OUTDIRBIN)/,$(notdir $(patsubst %.cpp,%,$1)))
endef

debug: CXXFLAGSREAL=$(CXXFLAGSDEB)
debug: clean
    @mkdir -p $(OUTDIRBIN)
    @ $(foreach s,$(SRCFILESTOOLS),$(call compile,$(s)))
    @echo "\n"

release: CXXFLAGSREAL=$(CXXFLAGSREL)
release: clean
    @mkdir -p $(OUTDIRBIN)
    @ $(foreach s,$(SRCFILESTOOLS),$(call compile,$(s)))
    @echo "\n"

check-syntax:
    $(call addFlags,$1)
    $(CXXCHK) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGSADD) -s -o /dev/null -S $(CHK_SOURCES)

clean:
    @rm -rf $(OUTDIR)
```

I tried several position changes in my makefile.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots; instead cut and paste the text with proper formatting. 
 Also please cut and paste the makefile rules into the question instead of linking to some external site.  Then we can help!

Comment: Please include the error output as well.

Comment: I started to write an answer here but... there's so much.  I recommend you re-write this makefile completely from scratch.  You should realize that operations like `eval` and `call`, and even `define` to some extent, are advanced topics and are only needed for very complex makefiles.  Don't use them until AFTER your makefile works.  You shouldn't be using `foreach` to loop through files inside a single recipe: list the targets you want to build as prerequisites and write a rule that builds ONE target file from ONE prerequisite.  Then let make figure out where and when to call it.

Comment: And the number one most important rule: never ever add `@` to your recipes until your makefile is working 100% correctly.  By adding `@` you're throwing away the single most important debugging tool for makefiles: seeing how make is expanding your recipe and what it's passing to the shell.  It's like debugging a program while sending all its logging and output to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Hi, as i wrote before, the makefile works correct. I can put a new directory to the src folder with a cpp-File and can use my Makefile without any modifications. Its worked 100% correct  so i want. The only thing is  why i can see just the additional @echo if have add more than one projectdir  in  src- subdirectoy.  It must have something to do with strange behaviour to compile call during foreach. So functional this Makefile is 100% correct and like  i want it. So  i dont need to rewrite  it from scratch again.

Comment: @MadScientist perhaps i can show via Zoom what i mean? That was the reason why i put a screenshot here first. But thankyou very much for your time to had a look. Thanks

Comment: As I said in my first and second comments, you should _cut and paste_ the output as text into your question, not as a screenshot.  See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: Your makefile is not really using make.  It's just a glorified shell script.  The goal of make is to build individual things, one at a time, and _only_ rebuild things that have become out of date since the last time it was run.  Your makefile will always rebuild everything every time you run it, so it would be simpler if you just ditched make and wrote a shell script that compiled all your files every time you ran it.  But, if you follow my advice above and remove the `@` characters from your makefile recipes you will likely see pretty quickly what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, for me its mostly easier to demonstrate the problem live or to make it more clear  with a screenshot. So its not a big issue because this Makefile works well  for me. It is more or less only an optical issue.  Not more. I like to have small Makefiles with biggest impact to use most stuff automatically. So in best case i have never to touch it again. For this i need to make function, eval and so on. ByTheWay. I try to use Make everywhere  for example to replace bower, grant, gulp, npm, scons, maven, ant, cmake and so on this whole bunch of not really needed build systems. make can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me state first that I totally agree with @MadScientist that this is not a correct way to use make. Thus said, the reason why is this happening is simple: the `define` itself is stripped of its final newline, therefore when you iterate with `$(foreach)`, the first line of the next invocation is put in the recipe in the same line as last line of previous invocation, which happens to also be `echo`. This way last `echo` from previous iteration displays your `@echo` coming from next iteration.

Let me give you an example. Given the following:

```
$ cat Makefile
define compile
        @echo "Compile $1"
endef

all:
        $(info $(foreach i,1 2,$(call compile,$i)))
        $(foreach i,1 2,$(call compile,$i))
```

You can see (with `$(info)`) how your statement is expanded. This is how it is invoked and the result is obvious.

```
$ make
        @echo "Compile 1"       @echo "Compile 2"
Compile 1 @echo Compile 2
```

One way to resolve it is to include additional empty line in the `define` so that it includes a newline and expands as needed:

```
$ cat Makefile
define compile
        @echo "Compile $1"

endef

all:
        $(info $(foreach i,1 2,$(call compile,$i)))
        $(foreach i,1 2,$(call compile,$i))
```

Now each iteration is placed on a separate line and is called as separate command:

```
$ make
        @echo "Compile 1"
        @echo "Compile 2"

Compile 1
Compile 2
```

Comment: Using `info` is a good debugging tool, but if you remove the `@` prefix you'll see it just as clearly: the `@echo` line will show up at the end of the `@echo "Compile...` line in make's output as well.